# Invoking a wmRoot service to get package list as a xml or json

Tags: webmethods

When calling GET on IS `/invoke/wm.server.packages:packageList` I get a result formatted as a table.
I would much rather get a format that I can use without much parsing hassle.

```
<BODY bgcolor=#dddddd>
    <TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
        <TR>
            <TD valign="top">
                <B>packages</B>
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <TABLE>
...
                            <TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
                                <TR>
                                    <TD valign="top">
                                        <B>name</B>
                                    </TD>
                                    <TD>PackageNameX</TD>
                                </TR>
...
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
```

How to get a decent output in `xml` or `json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to add content negotiation to the request header.

`Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8`